# How to call a bean's method from command line

Tags: spring, command-line

I have defined a Spring-bean:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="package.MyBean">
    <property name="name1" ref="otherBean" />
    <property name="name2" vallue="2" />
</bean>
```

And I know, that it implements a certain method, e.g. `MyBean.execute()`.

Can I launch this method from command line? How?
(Something like `java -jar ... myBean.execute`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load it up in a main method, look up the bean and call the method this way:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:yourcontext.xml");
        ctx.registerShutdownHook();
        MyBean myBean = ctx.getBean("myBean", MyBean.class);
        myBean.execute();
    }
}
```